# UITableView offset in UINavigationViewController, displayed under UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

On iOS 6, I am trying to reproduce the side menu left and right of Facebook app. I got 2 View controllers with their respective views added on the same window (just one bellow the other). My secondary controller is a UITableViewController embedded inside a UINavigationViewController (named "slide menu") that has a width of 300 pts -- frame : (0, 0, 300, 480).

Switching back and forward to the side menu is executing pretty well, but I have one tricky issue on that secondary view, if I push a view (the green one on the pictures) and pop it, my table view just goes bellow the navigation bar by 20 pts... I checked it deeply and it is the superview of the table view that doesn't start at 64pts (on the y origin) but only at 44pts.

What is really interesting is that using the EXACT same code, but just changing the frame of that secondary view controller from (0, 0, 300, 480) to (0, 0, 320, 480) fixes the problem! However any size different that {320, 480} bring back this issue...

http://d.pr/i/RNr4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this ?
`tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

Answer (score 0):

After hours of working on that problem I could not solve it directly. It appears that attaching a UIView (managed by UIViewController) directly to UIWindow is a terrible idea. I am suspecting that the framework is checking the size of the view and if it is not equal to the size of the screen (in other word if it is not "fullscreen") then it launches a relayout process on the view. The problem here is more like if the UIViewController doesn't have the information about the status bar so the relayout process is somehow screwed...

Anyway, the correct solution for doing this effect is to use one UIViewController and 2 child view controllers. One will be the slide menu and the second one the main view. Because they will be both correctly added to view hierarchy they will have the right information about Status bar and so on.